# How to connect a URL on StartUp without NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android

Im trying to develop an Android app that connects very firstly to my web instance and gets the startup information, then start my application according to that info.

I have tried to write URL connection code in my onCreate method, but when I run the app, it throws NetworkOnMainThreadException.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StartUp startUp = new StartUp(); // StartUp() constructor has URL Connection codes and this line throws exception
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl(startUp.getFirstLoadUrl());
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewHandler());
}
```

I shouldn't use thread for this because the other codes in my onCreate method must wait the output of the URL connection.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) that you start in the `onCreate` method which does the network communication in background (it's `doInBackground` method). While the task is running you can show some kind of progress dialog (or view in your activity) that lets the user know something is going on and (s)he needs to wait. At the same time this dialog stops him from doing something in your app (that needs some data fetched from your server, for example).

In order to continue with the execution of your code after the task is done you need to override/implement it's [`onPostExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) method to know when it's OK to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `AsyncTask`, do the network I/O in `doInBackground()`, and move "the other codes in [your] onCreate method" to `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 1):

On 4.0 onwards you cannot perform network operations on main thread so you should consider AsyncTask or Thread

Comment: Yes you can perform network operations on older versions (< api 11) in main thread